# AWS sagemaker datawrangler continues to be used after closing everything

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I used data wrangler for maybe 3h a week ago, and I open my account today to see that Ive been charged for 6 days worth of data wrangler usage. Basically it was running in the background the whole time. The first 25h were part of free tier then I got charged for the rest of the time. I dont have any endpoints to close so whats the issue? I dont care about the costs, I know I can talk to support to get the charges reversed but they dont seem to know whats going on because they havent helped me at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going over [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/data-wrangler-shut-down.html), I found that I needed to shut down the wrangler instance under Running Instances and Kernels button.